# WCF C# WebInvoke Operation contract error

Tags: c#, wcf

Buenas tardes, tengo un problema cuando intento crear un metodo que tome 2 parametros, si bien en el operationcontract le especifico que utilice Wrapped de todas maneras me da el error como si no lo tuviese.

Podrian Ayudarme por favor???

Interface:

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = 
"/DaysDeleteBusinessDay", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
[OperationContract]
void DaysDeleteBusinessDay(int BusinessesId, int Id);
```

Servicio:

```
[WebInvoke]
public void DaysDeleteBusinessDay(int BusinessesId, int Id)
{
    Logic.LogicFabric.GetLogicDays().DeleteBusinessDay(BusinessesId, Id);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta cambiar el `BodyStyle` de `Wrapped` a  `WrappedRequest`. Prueba si no quitando el `BodyStyle`

Comment: He intentado de las 2 maneras y nada, sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionar el problema, le agregue esto (mas abajo) a la definicion del metodo en el servicio, y funciono perfecto.

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
public void DaysDeleteBusinessDay(int BusinessesId, int Id)
```

Gracias!